# Installing AntlrDT on Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a): "The installation cannot be completed as requested"

Tags: eclipse

I've just tried to install AntrlDT, StringTemplateDT and XVisitorDT on Eclipse from the update site http://www.certiv.net/updates/.
However, Eclipse tells me "The installation cannot be completed as requested" (screenshot below). When I uncheck the proposed solutions, I can see the reasons for the failure:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: StringTemplateDT 4.9.0.20190203-0050 (net.certiv.stdt.feature.feature.group 4.9.0.20190203-0050)
  Missing requirement: Dsl Editor Core 0.9.0.20190203-0048 (net.certiv.dsl.core 0.9.0.20190203-0048) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.15.100' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Dsl Editor UI 0.9.0.20190203-0048 (net.certiv.dsl.ui 0.9.0.20190203-0048)
    To: bundle net.certiv.dsl.core 0.9.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ST Core 4.9.0.20190203-0050 (net.certiv.stdt.core 4.9.0.20190203-0050)
    To: bundle net.certiv.dsl.ui 0.9.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: StringTemplateDT 4.9.0.20190203-0050 (net.certiv.stdt.feature.feature.group 4.9.0.20190203-0050)
    To: net.certiv.stdt.core [4.9.0.20190203-0050]
```

so it seems some components are missing from the update site and this is a matter for them to fix, but I find the messages hard to understand. Is this the correct interpretation?

I am running Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows which options you have. Why the three plug-ins cannot be installed (which dependencies of which bundles exactly cannot be resolved) is explained on the previous dialog page. If you do not understand the explanation that is currently not included in your question, add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks. The previous dialog page is the one in which I select the plug-ins to install from the update site http://www.certiv.net/updates. When I select "Next", the progress bar gets activated and at first the message "Calculating requirements and dependencies" appears, followed by "Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while: 6/15". Please see new screenshot on question. So I don't see anything that looks like a clear explanation of why I cannot install the plug-ins. Thanks.

Comment: Please click _< Back_ on the _Install Remediation Page_ to see the explanation.

Comment: That's what I did. The second screenshot in the question was taken after clicking on < Back on the Install Remediation Page.

Comment: You're right, the explanation is shown on the first screenshot when you uncheck all the solution checkboxes.

Comment: I see. I got the explanations now, I will update the question with them. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the repository is incomplete: the bundles `bundle net.certiv.dsl.core`, `net.certiv.dsl.ui` and `net.certiv.dsl.ui` are missing in the given version range (the first two bundles in version 0.9.0 or higher and the third bundle of version 4.9.0). Please contact the owner of the update site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same problem with eclipse photon.

The components specified in your question are not installed because they require the plugin **org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.15.100**

[image: install remediation screenshot]

The fact is that Eclipse Oxygen/Photon install plugin version 3.14

I ask Eclipse Community Forums about how to upgrade org.eclipse.core.runtime to 3.15 in my Eclipse version ([see question](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1805001/#msg_1805001)).

They suggest instead to install last versions of eclipse (i.e. 2019-03) which come with plugin version 3.15.200

I installed new Eclipse and finally I could install AntlrDT successfully